# Magento 2 - How to print invoices in pdf from frontend (user account)

Tags: pdf, magento, printing, pdf-generation, magento2

I am trying to get a magento 2 shop up. I managed to install everything, but I am missing the link to get the invoice as a pdf on the frontend (which is mandatory for my clients). Here's what I have: 
[image]

As you can see, i have all the links to print the order, the invoice and All invoices, but they all take me to a html page, that prints like it, which is pretty annoying. I can't manage to find any solution to this problem. Is this a base feature in magento or do i really need to pay and install another module in order to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to finally get the answer to this problem by just adding a module to our magento 2 installation.
I provide the link of it.
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-pdf-invoice-extension/
It is working well for the past month now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your module **Vendor_Module**
2. Create route **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="standard">
            <route id="myroute" frontName="myroute">
                <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

3. Create front controller **app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Getpdf/Invoice.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Getpdf;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice as PdfInvoice;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;


class Invoice implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    const SELECTED_PARAM = 'id';

    protected FileFactory $fileFactory;
    protected DateTime $dateTime;
    protected PdfInvoice $pdfInvoice;
    protected RequestInterface $request;
    protected RedirectInterface $redirect;
    protected ManagerInterface $messageManager;
    protected ResultFactory $resultFactory;
    protected CollectionFactory $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param DateTime $dateTime
     * @param FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param PdfInvoice $pdfInvoice
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param RedirectInterface $redirect
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param ResultFactory $resultFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        DateTime          $dateTime,
        FileFactory       $fileFactory,
        PdfInvoice        $pdfInvoice,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        RequestInterface  $request,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory
    )
    {
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->pdfInvoice = $pdfInvoice;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

            $invoiceId = $this->request->getParam(self::SELECTED_PARAM);
            $filterIds = $invoiceId ? [$invoiceId] : [];
            $collection->addFieldToFilter(
                $collection->getResource()->getIdFieldName(),
                ['in' => $filterIds]
            );

            $pdf = $this->pdfInvoice->getPdf($collection);
            $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                sprintf('invoice%s.pdf', $this->dateTime->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s')),
                $fileContent,
                DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                'application/pdf'
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());            
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```

4. Now you are ready to use this controller. Just create a link and put there href with a path to our controller  (In some cases it is a good idea to use  **Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info** as a class to your block for getting order like  `$order = $block->getOrder();`)
5. Having an order information you can get invoices in your .phtml file

```
<?php foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice):?>
    <a href="<?= $block->getUrl('myroute/getpdf/invoice', ['id' => $invoice->getId()]);?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(__('Invoice (PDF)')); ?></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```